# How to get changing information from a webpage in Python

Tags: python

I am new with Python and am trying to create a program that will read in changing information from a webpage. I'm not sure if what I'm wanting to do is something simple or possible but in my head it seems do-able and relatively. Specifically I am interested in pulling in the song names from Pandora as they change. I have tried looking into just reading in information from a webpage using something like

```
import urllib
import re
page = urllib.urlopen("http://google.com").read()
re.findall("Shopping", page)
['Shopping']
page.find("Shopping")
```

However this isn't really what I'm wanting due to it getting information that doesn't change. Any advice or a link to helpful information about reading in changing info from a webpage would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Holy cow, far too broad a question. Welcome to Stack Overflow - questions here should be about specific coding problems.

Answer (score 0):

The only way this is possible (without some type of advanced algorithm) is if there are some elements of the page that do NOT change, which you can specify your program to look for.  Otherwise, I believe you will need some sort of advanced logic.  After all, computers can only do what we instruct them to do.  Sorry :)